# Minimal sum of a row in a spiral matrix

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

> Consider a spiral arrangement of a $5\times6$ matrix with entries from $0$ to $29$.
>
> \begin{pmatrix}20& 21 &22 &23 &24 &25\\
> 19 &06 &07 &08& 09 &26\\
> 18 &05 &00 &01 &10 &27\\
> 17 &04 &03 &02 &11 &28\\
> 16 &15 &14 &13 &12 &29 \end{pmatrix}
>
> Now consider a $100\times100$ matrix and consider sum of each row of the matrix. The minimum sum obtained in all such sums will be between $1501$ and $3000$.
>
> Prove this.

Here's what I tried : The minimum sum can be obtained from the 3rd row in this $5\times 6$ matrix which when extended to a $100\times100$ matrix makes a series, whose first order differences are in AP. I found the sum to be $19,503$ which way is above the given limits.

Comment: Have edited your quesiton with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), take a look and see how to format the matrix :D

Comment: Hey,thanks a lot!

Comment: The question is definitely wrong. It is fairly easy to see that the smallest sum will be in the row containing 0 and 1. The 50 entries on the right half are given by $4n^2+5n+1$, for $n=1 ... 50$. Those on the left are $4n^2+n$, for $n=0 ... 49$. I make the sum $341050$. I may be wrong, but it's definitely not in the $3000$ ballpark. Single numbers from the outermost spiral of the matrix are in the order of $10000$, obviously too large.

Comment: Isn't the sum to n terms of the series 1+10+27+52+.. is (n²+n)(8n-5)/6 ?

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+4k%5E2%2B5k%2B1+for+k%3D1+to+n) gets $n(8n^2+27n+25)/2$. In my previous comment I should have summed up to $n=49$. The last term in the sum is $4*49^2+5*49+1=9850$, which is far larger than the value that the question claims the whole sum should be, so the question is very wrong.